# Django app not connecting to PostgreSQL in setup created via docker-compose

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run a Django app with a PostgreSQL database via docker compose. Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  web:
    build: .

    command: sh -c "python manage.py runserver"

    volumes: 
      - .:/immoscreen

    env_file:
      - .env
    
    environment: 
      - APP_DB_ENGINE=${APP_DB_ENGINE}
      - APP_DB_HOST=${APP_DB_HOST}
      - APP_DB_PORT=${APP_DB_PORT}
      - APP_DB_NAME=${APP_DB_NAME}
      - APP_DB_USER=${APP_DB_USER}
      - APP_DB_PASSWORD=${APP_DB_PASSWORD}

    image: immoscreen_app

    ports:
      - ${DJANGO_APP_PORT}:${DJANGO_APP_PORT}

    expose: 
      - ${DJANGO_APP_PORT}

    restart: "on-failure"

    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    

  db:
    image: postgres

    volumes:
      - ./db/data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - ./db/init.sql/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

    env_file:
      - .env

    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - APP_DB_NAME=${APP_DB_NAME}
      - APP_DB_USER=${APP_DB_USER}
      - APP_DB_PASSWORD=${APP_DB_PASSWORD}

    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready", "-d", "${APP_DB_NAME}", "-U", "${APP_DB_USER}"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 5s
```

Here are the relevant parts of the `.env` file referenced in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
# PORT to run Django app on
DJANGO_APP_PORT=8000

# POSTGRES DB configuration
APP_DB_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
APP_DB_HOST=db
APP_DB_PORT=5432
APP_DB_NAME=immohub
APP_DB_USER=immohub
APP_DB_PASSWORD=thepassword

# POSTGRES DB configuration
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

This configuration uses a health check on the `db` service and a `service_ready`condition for the `web` service to not make the Django app start before the DB is ready.

The database is being initialized as expected with the initialization script stored in `./db/init.sql/`.

I can connect to the database with a pgAdmin client on the machine I am running this on with both of the following settings:

- `postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres`
- `immohub:thepassword@localhost:5432/immohub`

However, the Django app in the `web` container fails to connect to the database, even though the db container reports the database as rady to accept connections just before. Here's what the log shows:

```
immohub-db-1   | 
immohub-db-1   | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
immohub-db-1   | 
immohub-db-1   | 
immohub-db-1   | 2023-12-19 11:34:20.723 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg120+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
immohub-db-1   | 2023-12-19 11:34:20.723 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
immohub-db-1   | 2023-12-19 11:34:20.723 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
immohub-db-1   | 2023-12-19 11:34:20.724 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
immohub-db-1   | 2023-12-19 11:34:20.730 UTC [30] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-12-19 11:32:35 UTC
immohub-db-1   | 2023-12-19 11:34:20.736 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
immohub-db-1   | 2023-12-19 11:34:30.348 UTC [41] FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
immohub-web-1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
immohub-web-1  | Performing system checks...
immohub-web-1  | 
immohub-web-1  | 
immohub-web-1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
immohub-web-1  | Exception in thread django-main-thread:
immohub-web-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
immohub-web-1  |     self.connect()
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
immohub-web-1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
immohub-web-1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
immohub-web-1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
immohub-web-1  |     
immohub-web-1  | connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg/connection.py", line 738, in connect
immohub-web-1  |     
immohub-web-1  | raise ex.with_traceback(None)
immohub-web-1  | psycopg.
immohub-web-1  | OperationalError: connection failed: Connection refused
immohub-web-1  |        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
immohub-web-1  | 
immohub-web-1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
immohub-web-1  | 
immohub-web-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
immohub-web-1  | 
immohub-web-1  |     self.run()
immohub-web-1  | 
immohub-web-1  | 
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
immohub-web-1  |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
immohub-web-1  | 
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
immohub-web-1  | 
immohub-web-1  |     
immohub-web-1  | fn(*args, **kwargs)
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 136, in inner_run
immohub-web-1  |     self.check_migrations()
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 574, in check_migrations
immohub-web-1  |     executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
immohub-web-1  |     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 58, in __init__
immohub-web-1  |     self.build_graph()
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
immohub-web-1  |     
immohub-web-1  | self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations
immohub-web-1  |     if self.has_table():
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 57, in has_table
immohub-web-1  |     with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
immohub-web-1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 330, in cursor
immohub-web-1  |     return self._cursor()
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 306, in _cursor
immohub-web-1  |     
immohub-web-1  | self.ensure_connection()
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
immohub-web-1  |     
immohub-web-1  | return func(*args, **kwargs)
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 288, in ensure_connection
immohub-web-1  |     
immohub-web-1  | with self.wrap_database_errors:
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
immohub-web-1  |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
immohub-web-1  |     self.connect()
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
immohub-web-1  |     
immohub-web-1  | return func(*args, **kwargs)
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
immohub-web-1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
immohub-web-1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
immohub-web-1  |     connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
immohub-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg/connection.py", line 738, in connect
immohub-web-1  |     raise ex.with_traceback(None)
immohub-web-1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection failed: Connection refused
immohub-web-1  |        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I also tried with `localhost` as the DB host for the Django app, which fails the same way.

When I run `ping db` in a terminal of the `web` container, I get:

```
# ping db
PING db (172.22.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from immohub-db-1.immohub_default (172.22.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.263 ms
```

Can anybody see/explain what am I missing here?

Comment: Why are you defining the env vars in both an .env file and verbosley in the environments section. See the order of precedence rules here https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars-precedence/

Comment: The docker compose configuration looks good to me. However, I expereienced the same issue, it happens when your app container starts just after your db container but the latter take some time for initialize postgresql instance. You could try to put any delay to your app container and if it helps you probably need to find a way to make your app container wait when the database become available. I have written one for myself, let me know if you want me to share it.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Thanks for the pointer. I am just starting out with Docker, and I had an .env file defined before. Your link was very helpful, it looks like I can dispose of the .env file at some point (or leave out the environment config in the docker-compose file).

Comment: @IlyaKhrustalev I tried adding a health check as documented here and referenced in other SO threads: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ This dies not appear to have the desired effect, however, even though I can see the DB service be up and running way before I get any console output from the app container. Please feel free to share your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some troubleshooting, this appears to be related to how docker-compose builds the network configuration. There is no entry for the `db`service in the `web` service's hosts file. After adding one manually, the `web` service can ping the `db` host. I have created a new post on the issue tracker for docker-compose on Github: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/11293